# Script does not work after updating jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

There is a script that displays the archive of the publication. Initially, a list of years is displayed. Clicking on the year displays a list of issues. When you click on the issue it loads.

Initially, all years are displayed. Issues for years are hidden everywhere with display none, when click, it transforms to display inherit.

It should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="arrow">▲</li>
    <li class="journals">
        <ul class="ye">
            <li class="year">2019</li>
            <ul class="in_nums 2019" style="display: none;">
                <li data-issue="7633">№1(67)</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="year">2018</li>
            <ul class="in_nums 2018" style="display: none;">
                <li data-issue="6998">№1(63)</li>
                <li data-issue="7163">№2(64)</li>
                <li data-issue="7320">№3(65)</li>
                <li data-issue="7474">№4(66)</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="arrow">▼</li>
```

After upgrading from version 1.7.2 to 3.3.1, the following code does not work correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.year').toggle(function(){
        $('.in_nums').css('display','none')
        var y = $(this).text()
        $('.'+y).css('display','inherit')
    },
    function(){
        var y = $(this).text()
        $('.'+y).css('display','none')
    })
    $('.in_nums li').click(function(){
        $('#fresh').html('<img src="images/30.gif"/>');
        $.post(location.href,{'art_id':$(this).data('issue')},function(data){
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            var fresh = '<div class="lastjor">[[%babel.archive_[[++cultureKey]]]]</div>'
            $('#fresh').html(fresh+result.output)
            $('#latest').html(result.current)
        })
    })
    $.post(location.href,{'art_id':[[!getLastIssueID]]},function(data){
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        var fresh = '<div class="lastjor">[[%babel.lastjor_[[++cultureKey]]]]</div>'
        $('#fresh').html(fresh+result.output)
        $('#latest').html(result.current)
    })
})
```

It adds display none to the year of publications:

```
<ul>
    <li class="arrow">▲</li>
    <li class="journals">
        <ul class="ye">
            <li class="year" style="display: none;">2019</li>
            <ul class="in_nums 2019" style="display: none;">
                <li data-issue="7633">№1(67)</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="year" style="display: none;">2018</li>
            <ul class="in_nums 2018" style="display: none;">
                <li data-issue="6998">№1(63)</li>
                <li data-issue="7163">№2(64)</li>
                <li data-issue="7320">№3(65)</li>
                <li data-issue="7474">№4(66)</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="arrow">▼</li>
```

Has something changed in jQuery syntax or what could be the problem?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: I believe it is because you call `toggle`. What do you want to achieve by passing two functions to toggle, I did not see this in jQuery documentation?

Comment: @Adder you're right it's deprecated, and most likely the cause of the problem. The docs are here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes and that documentation states it has been not only deprecated but removed in 1.9.

Comment: Always worth looking at the upgrade guide when upgrading: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments you pass to `.toggle()` correspond to a use that was [removed from jQuery in version 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), and so these functions no longer correspond to click handlers. Instead the call to `toggle` will hide the selected elements and then execute the function passed as second argument.

To get comparable functionality on your page as it used to be with version 1.7.2, replace this:

```
$('li.year').toggle(function(){
    $('.in_nums').css('display','none')
    var y = $(this).text()
    $('.'+y).css('display','inherit')
},
function(){
    var y = $(this).text()
    $('.'+y).css('display','none')
})
```

with:

```
$('li.year').click(function(){
    var y = $(this).text();
    var isVisible = $('.'+y).is(":visible");
    $('.in_nums').hide();
    $('.'+y).toggle(!isVisible);
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! But there is still a small problem - initially, the list is displayed open, is it possible to display only a year first, and hide the issues before click on the year? https://clip2net.com/s/40HKaEF

Comment: Do you want the lists to be closed when the page loads? Then add one line before all the code that  I posted: `$('.in_nums').hide();`